# background image looks terrible on mobile

Tags: css, image, mobile

[image]

The picture pretty much explains the problem.

On mobile phones, my clean/crisp repeating background (position center bottom, repeat-x) looks like crap.  It doesn't actually appear that large on the phone - it looks visually the same size as on a computer, but - I assume since the phone is a higher resolution, it's making it look pixelated and choppy.

I can't believe I've never come across this issue before, but searches for the subject just turn up "how to make repeating backgrounds on mobile" or "how to do full-screen backgrounds on mobile"...etc.

How can I make a background image that will look clean/crisp/good on both mobile and computer?

I tried making the image 200dpi instead of 72dpi, but - no luck.

Comment: I wonder if any of these would work for you: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Have a `background-size` set? Could tinker with a % base to scale according to how many times you need it to repeat + width of the actual detail. - http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/8rs8zvt9/

Comment: I think a combination of both of your comments might do the trick.  Will try/thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst the optimal solution is SVG, the easiest way to do this is using pixel-density media queries.

```
e.g.
.container {
  background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');
}
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
  .container {
    background-image: url('images/bg-2x.jpg');
  }
}
```

If you are using preprocessors this becomes even easier as you can create mixins for different breakpoints including pixel densities.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you're suggesting I make an image twice as large for use on mobile?  the image is showing up the correct SIZE on mobile - it just looks bad.

Comment: Yes but due to the pixel density if you serve a 2x image and then set the height/width as the same as desktop then you will get a crisp finish.

Comment: I get that, but in this case, i'm not setting any height or width.

Comment: Here is a good article that might explain it better than I can. Unless the image is fullscreen is there any reason why you can't set a height or width?
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-right-way-to-retinafy-your-websites--net-31793

Comment: The image is a repeating background image.  How would I set it's height and width?

Comment: As I don't know the situation it's hard to say but by using one of the background-size properties. Contain could work if your trying to achieve what I think as this will keep the whole image inside the container despite it being 2x.

Comment: Had to set the size to a percentage - wouldn't work as a px size, but the pixel-ratio media query and background-size combination seems to be the answer.  Thanks.