# Background image looks blurry on mobile

Tags: css, image, icons

Left side image is Desktop screenshot and the right side image is Mobile screenshot. See the right side screenshot, image icons showing blurry. Can you please tell me what's the solution for it?

[image]
[image]

Please note, I have also tried the following solution. But, don't working.
[background image looks terrible on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248215/background-image-looks-terrible-on-mobile)

Comment: are the images .svg .png what?

Comment: My image is `.png` format. Please find the image url, https://i.imgur.com/4DulU2k.png

Comment: use a bigger image, use the css "background-size:contain;" 
https://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/creating-retina-images-for-your-website/

Comment: If I use `contain` icons don't showing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use an image with high resolution and quality.

The image you are using is ~ 10kb ...use image bigger image for this, you have to save your image with high dpi .

For mare details please refer this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch

Comment: This is the current dimensions and resolutions of this image. Plese find the following link, http://prntscr.com/lexlct and suggest me what I need to improved.